# Running World of tank under Wine

Tags: wine, winetricks

here is the biggest problem with Ubuntu for me: make WOT playable under Ubuntu with only Wine, with good performance.

I made a lot of research and finaly i found the solution in some world of tanks forum, here is the way in the response below to definitly play without bug to World Of Tanks on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (tested in many Ubuntu 14 computer, and in Ubuntu 15 too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1, first, of course, download the WoT_internet_install_eu.exe** of installation: http://worldoftanks.eu/en/update anywhere you want.

**2, open a terminal, and install wine and wintricks if you havn't alreaydy:**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5 wine-gecko1.5 wine-mono0.0.8 winetricks
```

**3, then install Ie7:**

```
winetricks ie7
```

now run

```
wine 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore'
```

- if it's fail, then you have to create a wine profile (i never done that, but see the doc here: https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wine_profils).
- if it's works, then continiue

**4, here is the magic line for wine:**

```
winetricks d3dx9_36 d3dx9_43 vcrun2008 msxml3 wininet corefonts ie7 d3dcompiler_43
```

**NOTE:** it will open ie7 and nautilus, you have to:

- Download the file `msxml3.msi` at this page: http://telecharger.cnet.com/Microsoft-XML-Parser-MSXML-3-0-Service-Pack-7-SP7/3001-7241_4-10731613.html?hlndr=1
- Put it in the folder `~/.cache/winetricks/msxml3/`

**5, then you have to use the Useful Registry Keys of wine**

```
wine regedit
```

This will open the registry key of wine, then do this step:

- On the left, open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, then open `Software`
- Right click on `Wine` -> New -> Key (name it **Direct3D**)
- Right click on `Direct3D` -> New -> String Value (name it **VideoMemorySize**, double click on it and set `1024` into his value data

Finaly,

```
wineboot ; pulseaudio -k
```

**6, Here it is !**
You can now right click in your WoT_internet_install_eu.exe -> open with -> Wine and install it !

**6.1, OR if you already have world of tanks installed completly in your window** and if you can acces to the Window Volume, then simply go find the WorldOfTanks.exe and execute it (but your WoTLauncher.exe will be laggy

source:
http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/218192-how-torunning-wot-under-ubuntu-and-any-linux-perfect-way/